# Can't Start Carbon - 12.04 - Python Error - ImportError: cannot import name daemonize

Tags: python, bash, caching, macos-carbon

I am really hoping someone can help me as I have spent at-least 15 hours trying to fix this problem. I have been given a task by a potential employer and my solution is to use graphite/carbon/collectd. I am trying to run and install carbon / graphite 0.9.12 but I simply can't get carbon to start. Every time I try and start carbon I end up with the following error. I am using a bash script to install to keep everything consistent.

I don't really know python at all so would appreciate any help you can provide.

```
/etc/rc0.d/K20carbon-cache -> ../init.d/carbon-cache
/etc/rc1.d/K20carbon-cache -> ../init.d/carbon-cache
/etc/rc6.d/K20carbon-cache -> ../init.d/carbon-cache
/etc/rc2.d/S20carbon-cache -> ../init.d/carbon-cache
/etc/rc3.d/S20carbon-cache -> ../init.d/carbon-cache
/etc/rc4.d/S20carbon-cache -> ../init.d/carbon-cache
/etc/rc5.d/S20carbon-cache -> ../init.d/carbon-cache


Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/opt/graphite/bin/carbon-cache.py", 
line 28, in from carbon.util import run_twistd_plugin
File        "/opt/graphite/lib/carbon/util.py", 
line 21, in from twisted.scripts._twistd_unix import daemonize 
ImportError: cannot import name daemonize
```

Thanks

Shane

Answer (score 46):

```
pip install 'Twisted<12.0'
```

As you can see in the [requirements.txt](https://github.com/graphite-project/carbon/blob/master/requirements.txt), the newer version of Twisted does not seems to play well with it

Comment: Works for me too.  `pip list | grep -i twist` showed `Twisted (14.0.0)`.  When I did `pip uninstall Twisted` then installed `Twisted<12.0`, carbon was able to start.

Comment: Solved the exact same issue as above – Ubuntu 12.04

Comment: pip install Twisted==13.0

Answer (score 21):

```
pip install daemonize
```

then I opened /opt/graphite/lib/carbon/util.py and changed

```
from twisted.scripts._twistd_unix import daemonize
```

to

```
import daemonize
```

Comment: it works!. I'm curious that will graphite will fix this or we will have to patch this manually everytime? Is there anyway to avoid manual update /opt/graphite/lib/carbon/util.py?

Comment: I will answer my own question, do: pip install Twisted==11.1.0

Answer (score 2):

I tried with `pip install Twisted==11.1.0` but not got it downgrade my Twisted version. So, i renamed /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/twisted/ to other name. After i install twisted `pip install Twisted==11.1.0` and `sudo ./bin/carbon-cache.py start` works.

Answer (score 1):

You can likely remove refences to daemonize from `lib/carbon/util.py` and then it seems to work with `twisted 13.2.0`.  See carbon github `commit 1d0bdc5c6ac331fdcb6f6c0f897507fcf833f616` from Nov 18 2013

https://github.com/graphite-project/carbon/commit/1d0bdc5c6ac331fdcb6f6c0f897507fcf833f616

Answer (score 0):

Newest version of Twisted won't work.

Install version 13.0:

```
pip install http://twistedmatrix.com/Releases/Twisted/13.0/Twisted-13.0.0.tar.bz2
```