# twisted threadpool import fail

Tags: twisted, python-import, graphite, pypy

**Context:**

I am trying to launch graphite with pypy interpreter.

**Error:**

launching graphite(*) leads to

`ImportError: cannot import name 'threadpool'`,

even though launching a python (pypy) interpreter and typing `from twisted.python import threadpool` works.

**Full stacktrace:**

```
15/09/2014 13:29:09 ::   File "app_main.py", line 75, in run_toplevel
15/09/2014 13:29:09 ::   File "/opt/graphite/bin/carbon-cache.py", line 30, in <module>
15/09/2014 13:29:09 ::     run_twistd_plugin(__file__)
15/09/2014 13:29:09 ::   File "/opt/graphite/lib/carbon/util.py", line 93, in run_twistd_plugin
15/09/2014 13:29:09 ::     runApp(config)
15/09/2014 13:29:09 ::   File "/home/vagrant/test2/site-packages/twisted/scripts/twistd.py", line 23, in runApp
15/09/2014 13:29:09 ::   File "/home/vagrant/test2/site-packages/twisted/application/app.py", line 380, in run
15/09/2014 13:29:09 ::   File "/home/vagrant/test2/site-packages/twisted/scripts/_twistd_unix.py", line 193, in postApplication
15/09/2014 13:29:09 ::   File "/home/vagrant/test2/site-packages/twisted/scripts/_twistd_unix.py", line 390, in startApplication
15/09/2014 13:29:09 ::   File "/home/vagrant/test2/site-packages/twisted/application/app.py", line 658, in startApplication
15/09/2014 13:29:09 ::   File "/home/vagrant/test2/site-packages/twisted/application/service.py", line 282, in startService
15/09/2014 13:29:09 ::   File "/home/vagrant/test2/site-packages/twisted/application/service.py", line 282, in startService
15/09/2014 13:29:09 ::   File "/opt/graphite/lib/carbon/writer.py", line 191, in startService
15/09/2014 13:29:09 ::     reactor.callInThread(writeForever)
15/09/2014 13:29:09 ::   File "/home/vagrant/test2/site-packages/twisted/internet/base.py", line 997, in callInThread
15/09/2014 13:29:09 ::   File "/home/vagrant/test2/site-packages/twisted/internet/base.py", line 989, in getThreadPool
15/09/2014 13:29:09 ::   File "/home/vagrant/test2/site-packages/twisted/internet/base.py", line 954, in _initThreadPool
15/09/2014 13:29:09 :: ImportError: cannot import name 'threadpool'
```

I am using pypy (2.3.1-linux_x86_64-portable) on centos 6.5
and have run pip to install twisted, whisper (and applied an additional [patch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19894708/cant-start-carbon-12-04-python-error-importerror-cannot-import-name-daem))

(*) test2/bin/python /opt/graphite/bin/carbon-cache.py --instance=a start

**Edit:**

- the virtualenv is called test2.
- test2/site-packages/twisted/python/threadpool.py{,c} shows twisted has threadpool
- `test2/bin/pypy --info` shows `[usemodules] thread = True`
- `'twisted.python.threadpool' in sys.modules` returns false just before the failing import

**Edit2:**

adding `from twisted.python import threadpool` earlier in the call stack (in /opt/graphite/lib/carbon/util.py for instance) works and make graphite work.

Answer (score 2):

Does your installation of Twisted have the threadpool module?  Look for a file named `threadpool.py` in the `twisted/python/` directory.  If this is missing, your installation of Twisted has been corrupted somehow.  You might be able to fix it by re-installing Twisted (perhaps destroying your ... virtualenv?  and creating a new one).

Does it have the stdlib threading module?  Twisted's threading support only works if the underlying Python runtime supports threads.  If this is missing you may need a different Python runtime.  PyPy supports threads but perhaps you got a build with threads disabled somehow.

If neither of these is the problem, you might learn more by running Python with import debugging enabled.  `python -v` enables minimal import debugging and `python -vv` enables more verbose import debugging.  I'm not sure whether these behave the same way on PyPy as they do on CPython.  Hopefully they do or things are a bit more difficult.

If that doesn't help then you might also try adding a breakpoint with pdb just before the import of the `twisted.python.threadpool` module and then stepping carefully through, inspecting state as you go.  One thing to check could be whether `sys.modules` has a `'twisted.python.threadpool`' item in it already, and if so, what value is associated with it.  `None` will prevent the import system from even looking for a module implementation on disk and just fail.

Comment: test2/site-packages/twisted/python/threadpool.py{,c} are present

Comment: test2/include/pythread.h suggests that thread are supported ?

Comment: All dead ends.  Time for `-v` and `-vv` probably.

Comment: sadly, pypy does not seem to support -v

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar problem. The problem was that in carbon.conf's USER setting, I specified my own user "graphite". When you do this, the carbon-cache daemon will run as this user. The graphite user did not have permissions to the twisted modules. Solution was
chown -R graphite /usr/lib64/python2.6/site-packages/twisted